# C programming to find divisible numbers

Tags: c

Write a C program to print all the numbers divisible by 3 or 7 between 300 and 700.(it's **OR** not **AND**)

I tried this program:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 300; i <= 700; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 7 == 0)
            printf("number = %d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but it's for AND not OR

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet

Comment: So replace AND with OR. Your book or tutorial should cover both operators.

Comment: `if((d3 == 0 || d7 == 0) && !(d3 == 0 && d7 == 0))`

Comment: "Programming" means writing the code yourself, not finding something almost right and ask someone else to fix it.

Comment: Once code finds acceptable values in the range [300 ... 320], The remaining acceptable values in the range [321 ... 700] are all 21 more than the prior set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem description is not quite precise enough: is it

- numbers divisible by 3 or 7; or
- numbers divisible by 3 or 7 but not both

For the first version, just use `||` instead of `&&`
For the second version, use the exclusive or `^` operator as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 300; i <= 700; i++) {
        if ((i % 3 == 0) ^ (i % 7 == 0))
            printf("number = %d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you could also use `if ((i % 3 == 0) != (i % 7 == 0))`

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty simple fix. Replace the `&&` operator with `||`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 300; i <= 700; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 7 == 0)
            printf("number = %d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the number cannot be divisible by *both* 3 *and* 7, see [chqrlie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77512703/15261315) for solutions.